# Bootstrap - AddClass on Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help, please, with Bootstrap. I have a `<navbar>` and if I click on a `<li>` from that `<navbar>` I want to be changed, and added a `class=active` on that `<li>`. I tried this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav li').click(function(event){
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');     
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This code only change my `<li>` but it doesn't redirect me to another page, but if I put this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav li').click(function(event){
        $('.active').removeClass('active');    
        $(this).addClass('active');    
        $('#content').load($(this).find(a).attr('href'));  
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It will redirect me to page that I clicked, but the `class="active"`, disappears. So, I need first when I click on that `li-a` => to be 1st redirected to page, and after, to `addClass` on my `li`.

Comment: redirect?? or load?? choose one

Comment: Can you add the HTML code?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/4qhuzgnCXUm86rCoUPii?p=info 
CODE HERE. If i click on a LI i want to be redirected to that A HREF from that LI. After that redirect, i want at that LI to be added a class - ACTIVE

Comment: On that code, when i press on LI, it;s added class - ACTIVE, but i doesn't redirected me. I know that i can't be redirected because i have a # on ahref, but, if i add something like index.php, my li won't redirect me, only class-active will be changed. Sorry for bad enligsh

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this would be to set the "active" class server-side when the new page is requested. Anytime you request a new page (by clicking a link or calling load) you are going to lose all the page state (as you've discovered).

Comment: And that... how can i do it?

Comment: Depends on what server-side framework you're using. If it's something like  PHP, you can conditionally insert the class into the markup based on the page requested. If you're using static html pages you can just hard-code the "active" class into the appropriate LI element.

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/4qhuzgnCXUm86rCoUPii?p=info .CODE HERE.
I use codeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work. What you need is to put the active class to the correct nav item in every single HTML page linked in the navigation. No javascript is required, then. Or am I missing something?

Comment: And how can i do it from my php page, then? Code is here: plnkr.co/edit/4qhuzgnCXUm86rCoUPii?p=info